# golint の "don't use leading k in Go names" とは？

Tags: go

[golint](https://github.com/golang/lint) に `don't use leading k in Go names` と怒られました。何故ですか？

動作例:

```sh
$ cat leading_k.go 
package main

const kFoo = 1
$ golint leading_k.go 
leading_k.go:3:5: don't use leading k in Go names; var kFoo should be foo
```

環境: Go 1.9.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

このルールはもともと、ハンガリアン記法で定数を表すとき先頭に `k` をつけるというやり方を抑制するために用意されました。golint に従うのであれば、ハンガリアン記法の `k` を使わず単に `foo` という名前にするなど、命名方法を見直しましょう。

ただ、ハンガリアン記法でなくてもたとえば `kB` という変数名はこのルールにひっかかってしまいます。二文字目が小文字だとこのルールにひっかからなくなるので `kb` などに名前を変えることで回避できます。また、そもそも命名法に欠陥がある場合もあるので、見直す機会かもしれません。

#### 関連

- [Question: don't use leading k in Go names. Why?](https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/258) -- golang/lint GitHub issues
- [Where does the k prefix for constants come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5016622/5989200) -- Stack Overflow